# Restricting search to a user's own department, if the user is not a manager

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I hate having almost two identical blocks do almost the exact same thing.

**I am working with Entity Framework 4.4.0.0

Asp.Net MVC**

Right now if the user is a "manager" I want to show them the entire list, if they are a normal user or a Team Lead.  I only want to show them their specific department.  The only different from both `model` is that one add's a where and the other does not.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    AD_CurrentUserProfile currentUP = new ActiveDirectory().GetUserProfile(User.Identity.Name.Split("\\".ToCharArray())[1].ToString());

    IQueryable<IPACS_DT_MasterList> model;

    if (currentUP.currentUser.isManager)
    {
        model = (from d in db.IPACS_Department
                        join f in db.IPACS_Function on d.departmentID equals f.departmentID
                        join pg in db.IPACS_Process on f.functionID equals pg.functionID
                        join sop in db.IPACS_Procedure on pg.processID equals sop.processID
                        select new IPACS_DT_MasterList
                        {
                            departmentID = d.departmentID,
                            functionID = f.functionID,
                            processID = pg.processID,
                            procedureID = sop.procedureID,
                            departmentName = d.name,
                            functionName = f.name,
                            processName = pg.name,
                            procedureName = sop.name,
                            owner = sop.owner
                        });
    }
    else
    {
        model = (from d in db.IPACS_Department
                        where d.name == currentUP.currentUser.department // only change
                        join f in db.IPACS_Function on d.departmentID equals f.departmentID
                        join pg in db.IPACS_Process on f.functionID equals pg.functionID
                        join sop in db.IPACS_Procedure on pg.processID equals sop.processID
                        select new IPACS_DT_MasterList
                        {
                            departmentID = d.departmentID,
                            functionID = f.functionID,
                            processID = pg.processID,
                            procedureID = sop.procedureID,
                            departmentName = d.name,
                            functionName = f.name,
                            processName = pg.name,
                            procedureName = sop.name,
                            owner = sop.owner
                        });
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge your if statement into the `where` clause.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    AD_CurrentUserProfile currentUP = new ActiveDirectory().GetUserProfile(User.Identity.Name.Split("\\".ToCharArray())[1].ToString());

    IQueryable<IPACS_DT_MasterList> model =
        (from d in db.IPACS_Department
                where (currentUP.currentUser.isManager || d.name == currentUP.currentUser.department)
                join f in db.IPACS_Function on d.departmentID equals f.departmentID
                join pg in db.IPACS_Process on f.functionID equals pg.functionID
                join sop in db.IPACS_Procedure on pg.processID equals sop.processID
                select new IPACS_DT_MasterList
                {
                    departmentID = d.departmentID,
                    functionID = f.functionID,
                    processID = pg.processID,
                    procedureID = sop.procedureID,
                    departmentName = d.name,
                    functionName = f.name,
                    processName = pg.name,
                    procedureName = sop.name,
                    owner = sop.owner
                });

    return View(model);
}
```

If the current user is a manager, the first condition will return true and cause the `where` statement to short-circuit; otherwise it will compare the department name to the user's department.